# I don't know how to Loop this code. Everytime I use while it just repeats the first printf sentece

Tags: c

I cant seem to loop this code. Its a simple code to display the smallest number typed, the biggest one, and how many numbers were typed by the user. Its also supose to quit if the user types in 0. Its in portuguese so look at the side of the commands for descriptions. It seems to be working properly but it only does it once and I cant figure out how to make it loop.
CODE:

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

int x,
    y,
    soma,
    maior;



printf("Digite o proximo  numero ou digite 0 para sair\n ");\\\Type the next number or type 0 to exit.

scanf("%d", &x);

y=x;

maior=x;  \\\maior = the biggest number. soma = amount of numbers and y the smallest number.
soma=1;

if(x==0)
    return(0);

else
    printf("Digite o proximo numero\n");\\\type the next number.
    scanf("%d", &x);

 if (x>maior)\\\If X is bigger then the biggest number so far.
   {
    maior=x;
    soma=soma+1;

    printf("O maior numero eh: %d\n",maior);\\\prints current biggest number
printf("O menor numero eh: %d\n", y);\\\prints smaller number
printf("A quantidade de numeros digitados foi %d", soma);\\\How many numbers were typed in

   }

else

    if (x==0)
    {
        return(0);
    }
    else

     if (x<y)\\If x is smaller then the smallest number so far.
     {
     y=x;
     soma=soma+1;

printf("O maior numero eh: %d\n",maior);
printf("O menor numero eh: %d", y);
printf("A quantidade de numeros digitados foi %d", soma);
     }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a looping statement in your code, you need to surround the part that you want to loop with while(true) or for(;;) block. Normally, when it gets to the end of the main function, the program simply terminates.

Comment: turn this into an endless loop with a for block:`for(;;) { /* your code here */ }`